# Jquery Ajax to WCF : Problem posting data

Tags: ajax, wcf

I'm having problems passing a strongly typed object to WCF service via Jquery Ajax.

JQuery:

```
    var var1 = "test1";
    var var2 = "test2";
    var var3 = "test3";

    var myObject =
    {
        StatusRequest:
        {
            Var1: var1,
            Var2: var2,
            Var3: var3
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UtilityService.svc/GetStatus",
        data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });
```

WCF:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string GetStatus(StatusRequest statusRequest)
    {
        return "hi";
    }
```

Class:

```
public class StatusRequest
{
    public string Var1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Var2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Var3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Fiddler:

```
{"StatusRequest":{"Var1":"test1","Var2":"test2","Var3":"test3"}}
```

I'm able to debug and watch the request come in but statusRequest is null.

Thanks

Comment: After I posed this I decided to try making StatusRequest in my javascript object lower case to match the incomming parameter in the WCF service and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StatusRequest` should be `statusRequest`

It needs to be the variable name not the class name.